# Can't parse String to Long and use it in list

Tags: java, android

I am getting some values in long `getJan();` from server and has to format this value so that i have some commas and look nicer. And put that values in List that accept longs, but DecimalFormat is returning String. I must covert to long so that I can put them in my list. I tried both `Long.valueOf()` and `Long.parseLong()`  but values are not shown.

For this post i put only one value but in future it will be more that why I am looping through list.

my code:

```
List<Entry> lista = new ArrayList<>();

        NumberFormat myFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
        myFormat.setGroupingUsed(true);


        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
        decimalFormat.setGroupingUsed(true);
        decimalFormat.setGroupingSize(3);
        Long jan = Long.parseLong(decimalFormat.format(netWorthPerMonth.getJan()));
     //   Log.i(TAG, "setSingleLineChart: " + jan);

        List<Long> listOfMonth = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfMonth.add(jan);
        

        for (int i = 0; i<  handleXAxis().size();i++){
            lista.add(new Entry(i, listOfMonth.get(i) ));
        }
```

Comment: A long value does not have 'formatting'. If you want the long to be displayed in a certain format you need to use the decimal formatting when you are displaying the data. Not when you are moving it around.

Answer (score 1):

A [long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) or an [int](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) can not have any decimal values. For decimal values you have to use either [float](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html) or [double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html). But if you want to format the value and display in a list you should probably go with a [string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).